# Python APNs does not process request

Tags: iphone, python, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement a server side script for sending push notifications to apple push notification server. I create the ssl connection, I send the payload - but am unable to get a response from the APNs. Here is my code:

```
import socket, ssl, pprint, struct, time, binascii

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# require a certificate from the server
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket( s,
                            keyfile="/Users/Jeff/Desktop/pickmeup-key2-noenc.pem",
                            certfile="/Users/Jeff/Desktop/pickmeup-cert2.pem",
                            server_side=False,
                            do_handshake_on_connect=True,
                            cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                            ca_certs="/Users/Jeff/Desktop/entrustrootcert.pem",)
                            #ciphers="ALL")
ssl_sock.connect(('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195))

print repr(ssl_sock.getpeername())
print ssl_sock.cipher()
print pprint.pformat(ssl_sock.getpeercert())

command = '\x00'
identifier = 1987
expiry = time.time()
deviceToken = "9858d81caa236a86cc67d01e1a07ba1df0982178dd7c95aae115d033b93cb3f5"
alert = "This is a test message"
sound = "UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName"
payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"%s\",\"sound\":\"%s\"}}" %(alert, sound)

packetFormat = "!cIIH%dsH%ds" %(32, len(payload))

packet = struct.pack(packetFormat, 
                    command, 
                    identifier,
                    int(expiry),
                    32, 
                    binascii.unhexlify(deviceToken), 
                    len(payload), 
                    payload)
nBytesWritten = ssl_sock.write(packet)
print "nBytesWritten = %d" %(nBytesWritten)

data = ssl_sock.read(1024)
print len(data)

ssl_sock.close()
```

Running this script, I generate the following output:

```
('17.149.34.132', 2195)
('AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
{'notAfter': 'May 31 00:04:27 2012 GMT',
 'subject': ((('countryName', u'US'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', u'California'),),
             (('localityName', u'Cupertino'),),
             (('organizationName', u'Apple Inc'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', u'Internet Services'),),
             (('commonName', u'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'),))}
nBytesWritten = 133
0
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? (I am sending enhanced push notifications so I am expecting a response from apple push notification server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to note is that read() is returning no data. In Python, read() is supposed to block until data is available or the connection closes. *Apple is closing your connection.*

Why? Well, probably because you sent a malformed request. `command=0` is a normal push notification; `command=1` is enhanced. The big-endian `1987` will be interpreted as a 0-byte device token and a 1987-byte payload, neither of which are valid.

(And FWIW, I'd use `B` instead of `c` for the command ID; it seems to make more sense.)

Answer (score 0):

you may consider https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs that wrapped lot of useful features, including:

- error handling
- support enhanced message format and auto resend messages which are sent before error response
- non-blocking ssl socket connection with great performance

Answer (score -3):

Apple Push notification server doesn't give a response, it's a one-way binary socket.
Rather than rolling your own solution you could try [apns-python-wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/) or [apns](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns/1.1)